# Ultra stable 5V supply

Tags: power-supply, 5v, stable

For a project where I'm using (very expensive) LED matrix, I need to power them with a 5V 1A power supply. At the moment I'm using a cheap wall plug switching supply, but I already know those things are jittery and I would like to know if you got any better suggestion to ensure the well being of my matrices.

Comment: I don't see a reason to worry. If you have a resistor or another current limiting device in series with the LEDs, it'd take a sustained peak at quite a larger voltage than nominal to damage the LEDs.

Comment: You should be fine with your setup. Did you check the output of your SMPS and saw excessive ripple?

Comment: What does the data sheet for the very expensive LED matrix say about over-voltage and over-current. You know, tolerances, absolute maximum ratings, duty cycle pulsing, stuff like that.

Comment: You can use a Zener diode for over voltage protection.

Comment: Usually expensive LED companies offer expensive power supply solutions too.

Answer (score 1):

[Computer power supplies](https://www.google.com/search?q=computer%20power%20supply&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=sb) are cheap, and generally put out a nice clean 5vDC.